FontAwesome size attribute does not change the size
I have the following code in my layout:
// Fontawesome
import { config, library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { far } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'
import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'

library.add(fas, far, fab)
config.autoAddCss = true;

I my component I am doing the following:
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'

// code
<a href="/onboarding/interests" className="px-10 py-3 mt-16 text-lg text-white bg-[#2967BC] rounded-lg hover:bg-[#004182]">
              <span className="flex items-center font-display">
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon="fa-brands fa-linkedin" size="2x" />
                <span className="ml-2">Sign in with LinkedIn</span>
              </span>
            </a>

When I try to change the size attribute the size change does not reflect.
Is there a way I can control this via tailwind utility classes?

Have you inspected the document to see if the size actually is being applied, but you can't tell due to calculated values being similar? Have you tried other, more extreme sizes as a test?

@isherwood yes. tried 10x to test no changes. referred this: https://docs.fontawesome.com/web/use-with/react/style

use size 4 in className
<FontAwesomeIcon icon="fa-brands fa-linkedin" className="text-red-500 size-4"/>
import { config } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core' 
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css' 
config.autoAddCss = false

Add the above code to the layout.tsx file in the root.
when importing icons do like this
import {
  IconLookup,
  IconDefinition,
  findIconDefinition
} from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'

const coffeeLookup: IconLookup = { prefix: 'fa-solid', iconName: 'fa-coffee' }
const coffeeIconDefinition: IconDefinition = findIconDefinition(coffeeLookup)

// ...

export class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={coffeeIconDefinition} />
        </h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

code snippets from https://docs.fontawesome.com/web/use-with/react/use-with

Any reason the attributes doesnt work? i was trying to animate as well and some reason none of the attributes seem to work.

import { config } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core' import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css' config.autoAddCss = false
add these lines in the layout.tsx

use these imports when using icons import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome' import { faFaceRelieved } from '@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons' 
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFaceRelieved}  className="size-4"/>

@DileepaMabulage, please put all information in your answer, not down here in comments. Also, give reasons for what you're suggesting. See [answer].

I had the same problem, In my case, I was trying to use Chakra UI and wrapping   <FontAwesomeIcon icon={coffeeIconDefinition} /> in the Icon chakra UI component, I put off the Icon component and the size starts to work.

You can change size of FontAwesome with Tailwind classes.
FontAwesome works just like other fonts in HTML and you can change color or size of them with CSS. For example:
 <FontAwesomeIcon icon="fa-brands fa-linkedin" size="2x" className="text-red-500"/>


the size does not seem to work when i use the size attribute. any idea how i can fix it

The question specifically states that the size attribute is not working. It shows the exact syntax you've suggested. -1
